# Why does my program rebuild all the parent rows when I change a value in a child row of *one* of the parent rows?

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I haven't been able to solve this problem.  I've got it down to where I just click a button, that doesn't change any data, in the child row, and the rebuild still happens.

I made methods to catch each of the eight lifecycle events.  When I push the button, the parent component (that contains all of the parent rows) hits these hooks:

```
ngDoCheck
ngAfterContentChecked
each parent row is revisited in here
ngAfterViewChecked
```

So I guess that means the activity is done during a view check.

I use ngForTrackBy to find out when each parent row is rebuilt.

The only oddball things are two:

```
1. The parent rows are not components.  (They were written before I came to the project.)
2. We are using Semantic UI.  I don't know what Semantic UI is doing behind the scenes.
```

The structure is like this:

```
table-component
    parent row (not an angular component)
        child-row-component
    parent row (not an angular component)
        child-row-component
    parent row (not an angular component)
        child-row-component
    . . .
```

The button in the child row that is able to trigger a complete rebuilt of the table component is just `<button>Nothing particular</button>`.

I haven't been able to make a simple test case.  I made a plunker, but the behavior disappeared.

Does somebody with a deep knowledge of either Semantic UI or Angular know why this is happening?

---

I was able to make the code run with Semantic UI entirely removed.  Same behavior.  So Semantic UI has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reload? Can you also post some code?

Comment: Are you familiar with OnPush change detection strategy? https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html I'm not familiar with Semantic UI, but this seems like a solid use case for it regardless.

Comment: I'll look into OnPush.  Thanks, Bagley.

Comment: I bet you anything, what you're describing is it, Bagley.  Turn your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: The OnPush writeup describes Angular checking different properties, and traversing a tree.  It seems like the kind of thing that would lend itself to logging.  "I checked the component 'actor'.  It didn't seem to be different, so I checked the sub-component Movie."  Is there a way to get Angular to do that?  (There are quite a few connections of different types in the original code.  It would be nice if Angular could tell me which one is the problem.)

Comment: During the night, something occurred to me.  Pressing a button causes all the properties to be checked for changes.  But this is the button:  `<button>Nothing particular</button>.`  No properties are changed when the button is clicked.  No handler is attached to the click event.  Does just a naked click cause Angular to re-evaluate everything?

Comment: Aha!  I found this:  `Browser Async APIs supported \ 
The following frequently used browser mechanisms are patched to support change detection: \ 
\ 
all browser events (click, mouseover, keyup, etc.) \ 
setTimeout() and setInterval() \ 
Ajax requests \ \ 
In fact many other browser APIs are patched by Zone.js to transparently trigger Angular 2 change detection, such as for example Websockets. Have a look at the Zone.js test specifications to see what is currently supported.`  Here's the url:  https://jhades-blog.herokuapp.com/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/